# Asymptotic Expansion or Perturbation of an Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

Consider the following ordinary differential equation.
$$u''+f(u)=0, \tag1$$
where $''$ stands for second derivative, and $f\in C^1(-\infty,\infty)$, $f(0)=0,\,f'(0)=1$. 
Multiply both sides by $u'$ and integrate over $x$ from $a$ to $x$,
$$\frac12u'(x)^2+F(u(x))=\frac12u'(a)^2+F(u(a))=\frac{c^2}2 \tag2$$
where $F(u)=\int_0^u f(t)dt$ and some positive constant $c$.

Suppose $c$ is very small. It is plausible that $F(u)=\frac12u^2+O(u^3)$ and 
$$\frac{c^2}2=\frac12u'(x)^2+F(u(x))\approx \frac12u'(x)^2+\frac12u^2$$
or as $u$ depends on both $c$ and $x$,
$$u(c,x)\approx c\sin x, \tag3$$
and
$$\lim_{c\rightarrow 0}\frac{u(c,x)}{c}=\sin x. \tag4$$

How does one rigorously justify this, perhaps in terms of asymptotic expansion and expand further in perturbative fashion?

Comment: For the final approximate equation, I would start with a Taylor expansion, and take only the first two or three terms.

Comment: Your function $f$ should be defined also for $u$ negative. But as far as I understand you don't want to assume $C^1$?

Comment: @Squirtle: Where do you think $F(u)=\frac12u^2+O(u^3)$ comes from? Taylor expansion of $f(u)$ of course. The question is NOT coming up with Taylor expansion but to justify it.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh: I edited the question according to your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Can we do it in more geometrical fashion? (By $v$ denote $u'$) Solutions of $u'' + f(u) = 0$ lie on level sets of $\frac{v^2}{2} + F(u) $, solutions of $u'' + u = 0$ lie on level sets of $\frac{v^2}{2} + \frac{u^2}{2} $. Your question now becomes the question of how close one curve to another. The possible caveat is that these two curves (defined as $v = g(u)$ are defined on different (but close to each other) intervals.

Comment: @Evgeny: The level set is exactly what Equation (2) is expressing. It is also called phase space. But how does one justify it rigorously?

Comment: I don't understand, what exactly you want to justify here.

Comment: @Evgeny: Equation (3) and (4) needs justification/proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the Cauchy problem: $u(0)=0$, $u'(0)=c$ with $c\neq 0$. We write the solution as $u(t)=cw(t)$. Then $w(t)=w_c(t)$ verifies the ode:
$$ w''(t)+\frac{1}{c} f(cw(t)) = 0, \ \ w(0)=0, w'(0)=1$$
The hypothesis on $f$ shows that $g(c,w)=f(cw)/c=\int_0^w f'(cs)\;ds$ is $C^1$ in $w$ and if we set $g(0,w)=w$ it is also continuous in $c$ in a neighborhood of $0$. The  problem for $c=0$ is simply $w_0''+w_0=0, w_0(0)=0,w_0'(0)=1$ so $w_0(t)=\sin(t)$ and by continuity of solutions to ode's we have $w_c(t)-\sin(t)$ tends to zero uniformly on compact intervals as $c\rightarrow 0$.

If you assume $f$ is $C^r$, $r\geq 1$ then the function $g$  becomes $C^{r-1}$ in all variables so that the solution will be $C^{r-1}$ in parameters. So $w_c(t)$ is $C^1$ in both  $c$ and $t$ [V.I.Arnold, Ordinary Diff Eqns, Chap 2, sec 7]. If $f$ is only $C^0$ (but differentiable at 0 with $f'(0)=1$) then I somehow suspect you still get continuity of solutions at $c=0$, but I wouldn't know (at least for now) how to prove this.

Looking in the $(u,v=u')$ plane the function 
$ H(u,v)=\frac12 v^2 + F(u)=\frac12 (u^2+v^2) + o(u^2)$ is a first integral of the flow. For $c$ small enough 
$$ K_c =\{ H(u,v) = \frac{c^2}{2} \} \cap \{u^2+v^2<2c^2\}$$ is compact connected, which implies that a solution starting in $K$ (our case) exists at all times.
[see e.g. Arnold, chap 2, section 7, The extension thm]

To get more information, we go to the
 $w=u/c,w'=u'/c$ coordinates: We have $w''+g(w,c)=0$ and the function $G(c,w)=\int_0^{w} \frac{1}{c}f(ct)dt= \frac{1}{c^2} \int_0^{wc} f(u) du$  extends continuously to $G(0,w)=w^2/2$. The function $H(c,w,w')=\frac12 (w')^2 + G(c,w)$ is then a 1st integral for the flow. A level curve of   $$\hat{K_c}=\{H(c,w,w')=1\} \cap \{w^2+(w')^2<3\}$$ is a circle for $c=0$ and it is regular (non-vanishing derivative/gradient) so using the implicit function theorem we see that for fixed $c$ small enough, $\hat{K}_c$ will be diffeomorphic to a circle as well.

Consider the solution curve $(w_c(t),w'_c(t))$ with $w_c(0)=0, w'_c(0)=1$. For $c=0$ we know that $w_0(T_0)=0$, $w'_0(T_0)=1$ with $T_0=2\pi$. Now,
  $$ (c,t) \rightarrow w_c(t) $$
is a smooth map and the $t$-derivative at $(c=0,T_0)$ is 1 (so non-zero). By the implicit function thm there is a $C^{r-1}$ map: $c\rightarrow T(c)$ (defined in a nghb of 0) so that $w_c(T(c))=0$. But then $w'_c(T(c))=1$ because of the first integral. The solution is thus periodic with a period that depends $C^{r-1}$ upon $c$ (small).

Comment: I like this approach. But $c$ is not in the form of the question. We need to do something similar to the original problem.

Comment: Well, your c in (2) is like my c^2/2  but we use the same value in (3) and (4)?

Comment: I have corrected my $c$. +1 for your answer. Could you please expand your last paragraph into a full proof and think about proving the second last paragraph? I am very interested in seeing these. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I have several questions regarding your last two paragraphs. Could you please elucidate or provide reference for the details? 1. "Then for c2 small enough the (smallest) connected component $C$ of $H=c^2$ containing zero in the interior is compact connected, which implies that a solution starting in $C$ exists at all times." Why do we need zero? I would think because of the strict monotonicity of $F$ at least for small $u$, zero can only be contained by $H=c^2=0$ and is a single point. Why does compact connectedness implies the global existence of solution at all times?

Comment: 2. "So using the implicit function theorem we see that $w′2+2G(c,w)=1$ will be diffeomorphic to a circle as well". Here I suppose you are talking about $H(v,u) = v^2+2G(c,w)=1$, right? Should this statement be true for small enough rather than arbitrary $c$? Do you need to invoke, say, the uniform boundedness of $\frac{\partial G(c,w)}{\partial w}$ with respect to $c$ in addition to the implicit function theorem?

Comment: 3. Could you please explain the last two sentences regarding the periodicity? Is the period of the ODE solution or the flow, or are they one and the same? What do you mean by "period of rotation is $C^{r-1}$" --- is the period not a single number?

Comment: Ok, I don't have the time right now. Will try to elaborate these points tonight.

Comment: Thank you, Rugh. I suppose the reason you use the constraining set $\{u^2+v^2<2c^2\}$ to intersect the set $S_c=\{(u,v)|H(c,u,v)=1\}$ is to ensure the compactness of the resulting set. However, I suspect we do not need the constraining set, since $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$, and thus $G(0,w)=\frac{w^2}2$ that $G(c,w)<1\implies |w|$ is bounded for small enough $c$ and thus $S_c$ is compact for small enough $c$. Is that right?

Comment: As you don't specify the function $f$ for large values of $x$ it could be that for $c$ non-zero, $H(u,v)=c^2/2$ or in the second case $H(c,u,v)=1$ contains come component far away from the origin. It was just to avoid such sets.

Comment: You are right. I first thought of the problem with $f$ at large $x$ then concentrated on the small $x$ and forgot about the large $x$ end...